# How to read from a text file then convert the text into a string then an integer

Tags: c#

Ok so im trying to convert text from a text file to a string then to an integer so then I could use them in my array(I know there's simpler ways of stating how big a 2D array is but I just want to do it this way so I can learn).

Map.txt (First line in the text)
20, 20
Then is just a integer map that below.

Here is the code that reads the text and displays also the map, again I want to **Take the first line of Map.txt convert it to a string, then to an int so then I could use it for other things**

```
     static void worldLoad()
    {
        int counter = 0; //Why do I need to declare it as 0....
        string line;
        //Read the file 
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"Map.txt");
        while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            counter = counter + 1;
            if(counter == 1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
            }
            if(counter == 21)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How your file may looks like, I mean the sample input from the file. and what are you want the method to do?

Comment: You have it in a string, when you read it into `line` (the fact you declared `line` using `string line` should have given you that information). So there's half of your answer. Now learn about TryParse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to convert file.ReadLine() to a string, it's already a string. What you want to do is int.TryParse(). See below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    int output;

    //Read the file 
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"Map.txt");
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        int.TryParse(line, out output);
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            Console.Clear();
        }
        if (counter == 21)
        {
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your `StreamReader` in a `using` block :)